# Snakemake rule is not picked up and can not specify the output files

Tags: python, snakemake

I have a folder where the outputs of the rule are generated. I am having a real trouble running `snakemake` with it. If I do not specify the outputs in `rule all`, the rule (called `neo4j`) is not run at all. If I try running it manually with `snakemake neo4j` (which I would prefer not to), then I get an error:

> WorkflowError:
>   Target rules may not contain wildcards. Please specify concrete files or a rule without wildcards.

I tried specifying the outputs of the rule in different ways but none of them worked.

1. Using `expand`:

   ```
   expand('results/neo4j/{sample}/cells.csv', sample=samples),
   expand('results/neo4j/{sample}/genes.csv', sample=samples),
   expand('results/neo4j/{sample}/cl_nodes.csv', sample=samples),
   expand('results/neo4j/{sample}/cl_contains.csv', sample=samples),
   expand('results/neo4j/{sample}/cl_isin.csv', sample=samples),
   expand('results/neo4j/{sample}/expr_by.csv', sample=samples),
   expand('results/neo4j/{sample}/expr_ess.csv', sample=samples)
   ```

Generates a very weird error for a completely different unrelated rule (called `umap`):

> Missing input files for rule umap:
>   data_files/normalized/minus_2/cl_nodes.csv.csv

The path generation is completely messed up even though the folders are not connected in any way except for the `results` being the root folder of all of the outputs.

2. Using `dynamic`:

   ```
   dynamic('results/neo4j/{sample}/cells.csv', sample=samples),
   dynamic('results/neo4j/{sample}/genes.csv', sample=samples),
   dynamic('results/neo4j/{sample}/cl_nodes.csv', sample=samples),
   dynamic('results/neo4j/{sample}/cl_contains.csv', sample=samples),
   dynamic('results/neo4j/{sample}/cl_isin.csv', sample=samples),
   dynamic('results/neo4j/{sample}/expr_by.csv', sample=samples),
   dynamic('results/neo4j/{sample}/expr_ess.csv', sample=samples)
   ```

Gives an error:

> dynamic() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sample'

Ok, I tried removing `sample=samples` but no luck

3. Just `directory`:

   ```
   directory('results/neo4j/{sample}/', sample=samples)
   ```

Gives error:

> directory() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sample'

If I omit `sample=samples`, not working either. If I specify `directory` under `rule all` `output`, not working.

The rule I am having difficulty with is below:

```
rule neo4j:
    input:
        script = 'python/neo4j.py',
        path_to_cl = 'results/clusters/umap/{sample}_umap_clusters.csv',
        path_to_umap = 'results/umap/{sample}_umap.csv',
        path_to_mtx = 'data_files/normalized/{sample}.csv'
    output:
        base_neo4j = 'results/neo4j/{sample}'
    shell:
        "python {input.script} -path_to_cl {input.path_to_cl} -path_to_umap {input.path_to_umap} -path_to_mtx {input.path_to_mtx} -base_neo4j {output.base_neo4j}"
```

`snakemake` version is `5.2.2`

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

> Update

I modified the `Snakemake` file using suggestions of `Mali Akmanalp` and now `rule all` looks like that:

```
samples,=glob_wildcards('data_files/normalized/{sample}.csv')
   rule all:
     input:
        expand('results/pca/img/{sample}_pca.png', sample=samples),
        expand('results/pca/{sample}_pca.csv', sample=samples),
        expand('results/tsne/{sample}_tsne.csv', sample=samples),
        expand('results/umap/{sample}_umap.csv', sample=samples),
        expand('results/umap/img/{sample}_umap.png', sample=samples),
        expand('results/tsne/img/{sample}_tsne.png', sample=samples),
        expand('results/clusters/umap/{sample}_umap_clusters.csv', sample=samples),
        expand('results/clusters/tsne/{sample}_tsne_clusters.csv', sample=samples),
        expand('results/neo4j/{sample}/{file}', sample=samples,    
          file=['cells.csv', 'genes.csv', 'cl_contains.csv', 'cl_isin.csv', 'cl_nodes.csv', 'expr_by.csv', 'expr_ess.csv'])
```

and `neo4j` rule like that:

```
rule neo4j:
    input:
        script = 'python/neo4j.py',
        path_to_cl = 'results/clusters/umap/{sample}_umap_clusters.csv',
        path_to_umap = 'results/umap/{sample}_umap.csv',
        path_to_mtx = 'data_files/normalized/{sample}.csv',
        base_neo4j = 'results/neo4j/{sample}'
    output: 'results/neo4j/{sample}/cells.csv', 'results/neo4j/{sample}/genes.csv', 'results/neo4j/{sample}/cl_nodes.csv',
            'results/neo4j/{sample}/cl_contains.csv', 'results/neo4j/{sample}/expr_by.csv', 'results/neo4j/{sample}/expr_ess.csv',
            'results/neo4j/{sample}/cl_isin.csv'
    shell:
        "python {input.script} -path_to_cl {input.path_to_cl} -path_to_umap {input.path_to_umap} -path_to_mtx {input.path_to_mtx} -base_neo4j {input.base_neo4j}"
```

With such set ups I am getting the error:

> Missing input files for rule neo4j:
>   results/neo4j/plus_1
>
> Update

I removed this line from `neo4j` rule: `base_neo4j = 'results/neo4j/{sample}'` and then changed the `output` of the rule to:

```
 output: 
      cells = 'results/neo4j/{sample}/cells.csv', 
      genes = 'results/neo4j/{sample}/genes.csv', 
      cl_nodes = 'results/neo4j/{sample}/cl_nodes.csv',
      cl_contains = 'results/neo4j/{sample}/cl_contains.csv', 
      cl_isin = 'results/neo4j/{sample}/cl_isin.csv', 
      expr_by = 'results/neo4j/{sample}/expr_by.csv',
      expr_ess = 'results/neo4j/{sample}/expr_ess.csv'
```

and the `shell` command:

```
shell:
   "python {input.script} -path_to_cl {input.path_to_cl} -path_to_umap {input.path_to_umap} -path_to_mtx {input.path_to_mtx} -cells {output.cells} -genes {output.genes} -cl_nodes {output.cl_nodes} -cl_contains {output.cl_contains} -cl_isin {output.cl_isin} -expr_by {output.expr_by} -expr_ess {output.expr_ess}"
```

I do not like feeding in each parameter in the `output` but it is not working otherwise. I tried feeding in just `output` but it only feeds in the first item in the `output`, others are ignored for some reason. I asked a separate question regarding that:

[Snakemake passes only the first path in the output to shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52088953/snakemake-passes-only-the-first-path-in-the-output-to-shell-command)

Other than that, it is working now.

Comment: Is there a reason you're avoiding usage of `rule all`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I am definitely not trying to avoid it, but rather trying to write `Snakemake` file that would work. So, what should be changed in your view to make it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very easy to diagnose the full issue since you haven't provided the whole Snakefile, but here is what I can infer from what you specified:

The error message is unfortunately a bit misleading, but the gist of it is that snakemake starts from a list of targets. These targets are either files you specified through the command line, or files that are the input of the topmost rule of a snakefile. Usually this rule is named "all" or "main". Here you would specify the final list of files to be generated by default. An example for your case would be:

```
rule all:
    input: expand('results/neo4j/{sample}/{file}.csv', sample=samples, file=['cells.csv', 'genes.csv', ...])

rule neo4j:
    ...
    output:'results/neo4j/{sample}/cells.csv', 'results/neo4j/{sample}/genes.csv'...
```

Snakemake looks at the input of `main` to figure out all the files to be generated, then figures out what rule(s) to run (`neo4j`) with which parameters, in order to generate those, and what rules to use to generate the inputs of those rules, etc etc. So at the end of the day the very last rule, i.e. the "target rule" `all` is where everything starts, so you can't use wildcards there.

Notice that the output for `neo4j` is just wildcards (they have {} in them and refer to a hypothetical pattern that may match a file), versus the input for `all` is expanded to a concrete file names (like 'results/neo4j/123/cells.csv').

Often the way people get this error is that they don't have an `all` rule on the top of their snakefile, which leads snakemake to pick whatever other rule is at the top as the target, which happens to be a rule that has a wildcard.

You probably shouldn't need dynamic / directory / etc for something like this.

Comment: Thank you! I updated the question with your suggestions and still getting an error (please, see at the top)

Comment: Probably `base_neo4j` needs to be specified in the `rule all` too somehow, but I am not sure on that

Comment: Ok, no worries, I rewrote it to use direct paths. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you have a static value like that, you can probably pass that in as a `params` and then use `params.base_neo4j` to access the value: https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#non-file-parameters-for-rules