# Snakemake passes only the first path in the output to shell command

Tags: python, snakemake

I am trying to feed all of the paths at once in one variable to a `python` script in `snakemake` like that:

```
rule neo4j:
  input:
      script = 'python/neo4j.py',
      path_to_cl = 'results/clusters/umap/{sample}_umap_clusters.csv',
      path_to_umap = 'results/umap/{sample}_umap.csv',
      path_to_mtx = 'data_files/normalized/{sample}.csv'
  output: 'results/neo4j/{sample}/cells.csv', 'results/neo4j/{sample}/genes.csv', 
      'results/neo4j/{sample}/cl_nodes.csv', 'results/neo4j/{sample}/cl_contains.csv',
      'results/neo4j/{sample}/cl_isin.csv', 'results/neo4j/{sample}/expr_by.csv',
      'results/neo4j/{sample}/expr_ess.csv'
  shell:
      "python {input.script} -path_to_cl {input.path_to_cl} -path_to_umap {input.path_to_umap} -path_to_mtx {input.path_to_mtx} -output {output}"
```

When I am accessing `output` parameter in the `python` script it sees only the first path: `'results/neo4j/{sample}/cells.csv'`. I have also tried naming each path, but it did not fix the issue. How to pass all paths in the `output` of the rule as an array or as dictionary to be able to access them later in `python`?

Comment: That's weird. I tested your code using snakemake `v5.2.2` on mac, and it works as expected listing all output files in shell command. What happens when you name each output file?

Comment: It just takes in the first one in the `output`, same basically

Comment: I mean, does snakemake produce error if second output file was called `b` and you refer to it in shell command as `{output.b}`?
Which snakemake version and OS are you using? Did you try using `run` as suggested in answer section? This would show you if `output` does recognize all the files listed as part of `output`.

Comment: No, this way it is working fine, but it is just not how I want. This way I would need to manually feed in each parameter pretty much. OS is macOS High Sierra 10.13.4, and Snakemake version is 5.2.2. Not tried using run, since I need a shell to run a python script, right? Can I run python script from ‘run’?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are trying to get to. Could you show us the resolved shell command created by snakemake using your current code and also the shell command that you want it to be?

Comment: I just want to input many paths at the same time into the python script, and that is it. As a single variable. Like pass a dictionary or an array, and then access it.

Comment: Snakemake can't do that on its own, but your python script can be used to achieve that - Use double quotes for output in shell command `"-output {output}"`, and in your python script, split them into list with space as delimiter. This should work assuming none of your output path has space character in them.

Comment: Ok, I see, passing as a string, then manipulating it. Got it, thank you!

Comment: My understanding is that the resulting shell command-line should end with "-output <file1> <file2> ..." with the file names space-separated. It is then your responsibility to have your script accept a space-separated list of files (see argparse). Another idea would be to pass a pickled python dictionary as input to your script, so you would first need a rule that generates this pickled dictionary, and then use the output of this rule as input for your `neo4j` rule. Note that you do not actually need to use `{output}` in the shell section. You just need to be sure your script will generate it.

Comment: @NikitaVlasenko Regarding one of your questions in the comments: yes, you can start a python script using `run`. One way to do is to use `shell("python ...")` inside the `run` section.

Comment: Ок, so probably I can also then use for loop there, form an array of paths, and then path it to the python script? Would that work? Or just passing ‘output’ should start working? Will try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly your issue, your problem is that the `neo4j.py` script doesn't accept more than one file for its `-output` argument: The shell command probably ends with the full list of files (check with the `-p` option of `snakemake`), but only the first one is taken into account by the script.

If that is indeed the case, a possibly cleaner approach would be to modify the interface of your `neo4j.py` script so that it uses one argument for each of its output files.

You would then modify your rule as follows:

```
rule neo4j:
    input:
        script = 'python/neo4j.py',
        path_to_cl = 'results/clusters/umap/{sample}_umap_clusters.csv',
        path_to_umap = 'results/umap/{sample}_umap.csv',
        path_to_mtx = 'data_files/normalized/{sample}.csv'
    output:
        cells = 'results/neo4j/{sample}/cells.csv',
        genes = 'results/neo4j/{sample}/genes.csv',
        nodes = 'results/neo4j/{sample}/cl_nodes.csv',
        contains = 'results/neo4j/{sample}/cl_contains.csv',
        isin = 'results/neo4j/{sample}/cl_isin.csv',
        by = 'results/neo4j/{sample}/expr_by.csv',
        ess = 'results/neo4j/{sample}/expr_ess.csv'
    shell:
        """
        python {input.script} \\
            --path_to_cl {input.path_to_cl} \\
            --path_to_umap {input.path_to_umap} \\
            --path_to_mtx {input.path_to_mtx} \\
            --cells {output.cells} \\
            --genes {output.genes} \\
            --nodes {output.nodes} \\
            --contains {output.contains} \\
            --isin {output.isin} \\
            --by {output.by} \\
            --ess {output.ess}
        """
```

Some potentially useful python modules to set up the interface of your script:

- [docopt](https://github.com/docopt/docopt)
- [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html)

---

#### Edit

If you don't want to pass each input file as an individual argument, you could simply pass the output directory, and let your script build the output paths from this single parameters. Given the file names you want, this seems possible:

```
rule neo4j:
    input:
        script = 'python/neo4j.py',
        path_to_cl = 'results/clusters/umap/{sample}_umap_clusters.csv',
        path_to_umap = 'results/umap/{sample}_umap.csv',
        path_to_mtx = 'data_files/normalized/{sample}.csv'
    output:
        'results/neo4j/{sample}/cells.csv',
        'results/neo4j/{sample}/genes.csv',
        'results/neo4j/{sample}/cl_nodes.csv',
        'results/neo4j/{sample}/cl_contains.csv',
        'results/neo4j/{sample}/cl_isin.csv',
        'results/neo4j/{sample}/expr_by.csv',
        'results/neo4j/{sample}/expr_ess.csv'
    shell:
        """
        python {input.script} \\
            --path_to_cl {input.path_to_cl} \\
            --path_to_umap {input.path_to_umap} \\
            --path_to_mtx {input.path_to_mtx} \\
            --out_dir results/neo4j/{wildcards.sample}
        """
```

Comment: That’s how I am doing that and I just do not want it that way.

Comment: @NikitaVlasenko What I tend to do in such cases is to only give the output directory to my script: `"python {input.script} <input files> -output results/neo4j/{wildcards.sample}"` (remember that you do not need to use `{output}` in the shell part)

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
rule hello:
    output:
        "woot", "hoot"
    run:
        for f in output:
            print(f)
        print(output[1])
```

prints "woot", "hoot", "hoot".